# How does Armor Rating work in Dragon Age: Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

While the elemental resistances seem pretty obvious, I didn't find any hints on how exactly the armor rating works. This is a bit of a disadvantage when deciding which items to equip as I have no idea how much those few points of additional armor rating actually do, and whether they're better than the alternative.

From how it is described I assume that the armor rating only applies to physical attacks, and not at all to magical ones. But how much damage reduction does the armor rating actually apply?

Answer (score 4):

For the player, armor reduces the damage taken by physical attacks by 2 for every armor point in the campaign, or by 1 in multiplayer.

Armor on monsters reduces the damage taken by 1 per point.

Armor is applied after damage multipliers (like %-Attack, Crit, etc.) but before damage reduction from % melee defense.

The formulas for damage taken are:

For monsters:
`[WeaponDmg * (1 + Attk%) * (1 + CritDmg%) * (1 + FlankDmg%) * (1 + BarrierDmg%) * (1 + GuardDmg%) - Armor *(1 - ArmorPen%)] * AbilityMultiplier%`

For the player:
`[BaseDmg * (1 + CritDmg%) * (1 + FlankDmg%) - Armor * 2(only in solo mode) *(1 - ArmorPen%)] * (1 - Defense%) * (1 - ElementalDef%)`

Source: http://dragonage3.wiki.fextralife.com/Attributes